# If I have two iframes that share a domain, will a postmessage on one trigger a message event on the other?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two iframes on the same host page

```
<body>
  <iframe src="https://example.com/a" />
  <iframe src="https://example.com/b" />
</body>
```

If I trigger

```
window.postMessage('Marco', window.location.origin)
```

from within the first frame, will a message event (also) be triggered within the second iframe?

Comment: seems like a simple test....

Comment: My tests show that it doesn't work, but perhaps I am doing it wrong

Comment: Well you are not targeting an iframe to send the message to. You are sending it to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

No, the message will only be sent to the window on which `postMessage` was called on.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

> *targetWindow*.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
>
> *targetWindow*:
>
> A reference to the window that will receive the message. Methods for
>   obtaining such a reference include:
>
> - window.open (to spawn a new window and then reference it),
> - window.opener (to reference the window that spawned this one),
> - HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow (to reference an embedded  from its parent window),
> - window.parent (to reference the parent window from within an embedded ), or
> - window.frames + an index value (named or numeric).

So  `window.postMessage` will only send the message to `window` and `window.frames[0].postMessage` will only send the message to the iframe.

Comment: Would you be able to pass a MessageChannel from one iframe to another or will you need to have a message broker living on the host page for cross frame communication?

Comment: I don't know and I think this is too much to discuss in the comments, you should probably post this as a separate question.